# Error: Nothing was returned from render... in MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to render picture equals to chosen color, but I'm getting the following error for some reason:

> Uncaught Error: RenderProductImage(...): Nothing was returned from
> render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to
> render nothing, return null.

Here are my functions:

```
const {productData} = useContext(ProductContext);
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [color, setColor] = useState([]);

const ParsedColors = props => {
        return(
            props.product.color.map(col => {
                const parsed = JSON.parse(col)
                return(
                    <button name="color" value={parsed.value} style={{backgroundColor: `${parsed.value}`}} onClick={() => colorPicker([props.product._id, parsed.value])}/>
                )
            })
        )
    }

    const colorPicker = ([productId, colors]) => {
        setColor([productId, colors])
        if(products.some(product => product._id === productId)) {
            RenderProductImage(products.find(product => product._id === productId))
        }
    }

    const RenderProductImage = (product) => {
        return(
            product.imageFile?.map(image => {
                if(image.originalname.includes(color[1]?.substring(1))) {
                    return (
                        <img src={require(`./styles/images/${image.originalname}`).default} alt="product img" />
                    )
                }
            })    
        )
    }
```

Here is how I use it:

```
{color.length > 0 ?
         <RenderProductImage />
        :
         <>
           {product.imageFile.map(image => {
             if(image.originalname.includes('def')) {
             return (
             <img src={require(`./styles/images/${image.originalname}`).default} alt="product img" />
             )
           }
         })}
        </>
       }
       <div className="product--Colors--Container">
          <ParsedColors product={product}/>
       </div>
```

So the condition is working and the image that includes('def') is rendering but when I choose color I'm getting the error.

**UPDATE:**

Function:

```
const RenderProductImage = props => {
        if(products.some(product => product._id === props.productId)) {
            return(
                products.find(product => product._id === props.productId).imageFile?.map(image => {
                    if(image.originalname.includes(color[1].substring(1))) {
                        return (
                            <img src={require(`./styles/images/${image.originalname}`).default} alt="product img" />
                        )
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
```

Use:

```
 {color.length > 0 ?
                                            <RenderProductImage product={product} />
                                        :
                                        <>
                                            {product.imageFile.map(image => {
                                                if(image.originalname.includes('def')) {
                                                    return (
                                                        <img src={require(`./styles/images/${image.originalname}`).default} alt="product img" />
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            })}
                                        </>
```

Colors data:

[image]

Comment: You need to pass product props in `RenderProductImage` and then use in function same way as how you are doing in `ParsedColors`

Comment: No, when you send `productId` in `RenderProductImage` then you need to access it by `props.productId` same as you are accessing product in `ParsedColors` with `props.product`

Comment: Yes I saw it but

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Now when I choose a color for a product it change the image for all products, not just for the choosen one, that's why I was trying to make it like I show first

Comment: To take the ID of the chosen one and change only his image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `RenderProductImage` function like below:-

```
    const RenderProductImage = (props) => {
        return(
            props.product.imageFile?.map(image => {
                if(image.originalname.includes(color[1]?.substring(1))) {
                    return (
                        <img src={require(`./styles/images/${image.originalname}`).default} alt="product img" />
                    )
                }
            })    
        )
    }
```

Now you can access `RenderProductImage` like below:-

```
<RenderProductImage product={product} />
```

Change your condition to render product image like below:-

```
{(color.length > 0 && color[0] === product._id) ? ... }
```

Comment: So u mean to pass tha whole product object not just the ID ?

Comment: Yes and then you can check `imageFile` array and render `img` based on condition.

Comment: Okay that works but how can I make a condition for the other products that I didn't choose a color like the condition includes("def") (for default image), to stay unchanged. Because now if I choose a color the other product image disappear. I can show screenshot if u want

Comment: Then when choosing color you need to specify productId as well so later you can check that which color is related to product by comparing productId.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how you are storing color so Can you add that so we can take better look?

Comment: You can check the colors data (each product has that) I post a screenshot @Priyank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232548/discussion-between-yollo-and-priyank-kachhela).